Set up an ECDA server to allow SAP Replication Server to connect to SQL Server
I'm trying to set up an ECDA server to allow SAP Replication Server (RS) to connect to MS SQL Server.  I'm unable to get RS to connect even though I can isql to the server using the same interfaces file.  This is a new server to replace an existing ECDA/MSSQL server.  Looking at the existing server I noticed that I can login without valid credentials.  If I isql to the server with or without a valid login and perform select suser_name() the result is always NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.  Further investigation shows that the User being used by RS does not even exist as a user in the SQL Server.
SAP has not been able to help.  The existing server was set up in 2008 and the person who did it no longer works here.  Does anyone know how I can set up the new server to allow logins without valid credentials?  I realize that's a bad idea but it's all I have to go on.
I tried connecting RS to the new ECDA server but get this error:
I. 2024/06/17 11:17:20. SQM starting: 670:0 SQLSERVER2022.test_db
E. 2024/06/17 11:17:21. ERROR #1027 USER(sa) - seful/cm.c(4963)
        Open Client Client-Library error: Error: 101188867, Severity 5 -- 'ct_connect(): directory service layer: internal directory control layer error: Requested server name not found.'.
E. 2024/06/17 11:17:21. ERROR #13045 USER(sa) - seful/cm.c(4969)
        Failed to connect to server 'SQLSERVER2022' as user 'dbmaint01'. See CT-Lib and/or server error messages for more information.
W. 2024/06/17 11:17:21. WARNING #15542 USER(sa) - dl/ddldb.c(5722)
        Connection to server <SQLSERVER2022> failed. Command batch not executed. See the Replication Server error log for details.
T. 2024/06/17 11:17:21. (544): Command(s) intended for 'SQLSERVER2022.test_db':
T. 2024/06/17 11:17:21. (544): 'drop table rs_info'


It might be better to ask this question on ServerFault since it's more devops / sysadmin and less programming centric.

appears the ECDA/RS software can't find a reference to server SQLSERVER2022; RS connects (via interfaces file) to the ECDA which in turn connects (via ECDA and/or ODBC config files) to MSSQL; my ECDA knowledge is extremely old so I'd start by reviewing the RS/ECDA documentation and then see if you can reverse engineer all the bits-n-pieces that are currently in place for the working RS/ECDA setup
